# How to use sentiment package in R 3.2.0

Tags: r, package, sentiment-analysis

I am an ML enthusiast.Recently I have started using R and its packages.But I am not able to install sentiment package for R 3.2.0.I have googled about this problem. It says that sentiment package is no longer available for R 3.2.0.But I have seen in many github repositories where sentiment package is not used but still its files are being used.My main problem is how do I use sentiment package for R 3.2.0?

Comment: @figurine: The code of the possible duplicate does not work.  I left a comment for agstudy there describing the errors after score() [as well as an earlier SO question, unanswered, on a related error].

Comment: Looks like I can't add an answer but I can comment. I was able to install the tm.plugin.sentiment from github directly (for R 3.2.0):
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment")

Answer (score 4):

Here is a starting point. First is some code to install the sentiment plug ins (thank you, Dason, for the useful comment).

Next, with some text from a previous SO post to show what you might do, you can create a data frame.

**Install the packages for sentiment analysis:**

```
# install.packages("tm.lexicon.GeneralInquirer", repos="http://datacube.wu.ac.at", type="source")
library(tm.lexicon.GeneralInquirer)
# install.packages("tm.plugin.sentiment", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
library(tm.plugin.sentiment) # posted comments on SO about this not working
library(tm)
```

**Using the installed functions:**

```
some_txt<- c("I am very happy at stack overflow , excited, and optimistic.",
             "I am very scared from OP question, annoyed, and irritated.", "I am completely neutral about blandness.")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(some_txt)) 
pos <- sum(sapply(corpus, tm_term_score, terms_in_General_Inquirer_categories("Positiv")))
neg <- sum(sapply(corpus, tm_term_score, terms_in_General_Inquirer_categories("Negativ")))
pos.score <- tm_term_score(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), 
                           terms_in_General_Inquirer_categories("Positiv")) # this lists each document with number below

neg.score <- tm_term_score(TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE)), 
                           terms_in_General_Inquirer_categories("Negativ")) 

total.df <- data.frame(positive = pos.score, negative = neg.score)
total.df <- transform(total.df, net = positive - negative)

  positive negative net
1        3        1   2
2        0        1  -1
3        0        0   0
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: I tells how to install the sentiment functions and uses them in a test case.  That is what OP asked about.

Comment: Ok.  Their main question is getting it installed though.  I would suggest actually separating that out and explaining how to install it since that is the actual question.

Comment: Not to be argumentative, but the final sentence asks about how to use the package.  I tried to address both points of installation and use.  Possibly reconsider the down vote?  :)

Comment: I didn't downvote.  My take on the last sentence was just reiterating that they couldn't install it.  You can't use it if you don't have access to it.  I can see where you're coming from with that last line.  I still think separating out the install code and adding a little explanation would be a good idea and would net you an upvote from me.